# Removing unicode fonts not in the text from a presentation using VBA (PowerPoint 2013)

Tags: vba, fonts, powerpoint

I am in the process of coding an add-in to be used with a new template. One of the tools should go through an entire presentation and replace each font with a new default font. This is working fine, but I am having problems with unicode fonts.

Certain shapes within the presentation seem to have a unicode font linked to them, but not as part of the text (maybe the parent shape font?). When I replace the font, the text is changed, but I am still getting unicode fonts embedded in my presentations. When I try and detect the using VBA, they are not found. If I copy the text (no formatting) to a new text box, the unicode font disappears, so they are obivously linked to the shape formatting somehow.

I've tried changing .NameAscii/.NameComplexScript/.NameFarEast & .NameOther and this doesn't work either. Is there any way to access the parent font of a shape?

E.g. shp.textframe.parent.font.name =

My current macros are working fine, but I need to solve this problem, as when I save the embedded unicode fonts are making my presentation huge. Alternatively, is there a way to only embed certain fonts in a presentation?

Any help would be really appreciated! I've pasted my macros below:

```
Sub ChangeFont()

Dim x, y, a, b As Integer
Dim s As Slide
Dim shp As Shape
Dim ppt As Presentation
Dim pp2 As Presentation

Set ppt = ActivePresentation

On Error Resume Next

For x = 1 To ppt.Slides.Count
    For y = 1 To ppt.Slides(x).Shapes.Count

    Set shp = ppt.Slides(x).Shapes(y)

        If shp.HasTextFrame Then
            shp.TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Name = "FontA"

        ElseIf shp.Type = msoChart Then
            On Error Resume Next
            shp.Chart.ChartTitle.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Name = "FontA"
            shp.Chart.Legend.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Name = "FontA"
            shp.Chart.DataTable.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Name = "FontA"


        ElseIf shp.Type = msoTable Then
            For a = 1 To shp.Table.Rows.Count
                For b = 1 To shp.Table.Columns.Count
                    shp.Table.Cell(a, b).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Name = "FontA"
                Next b
            Next a

        End If

        ChangeFontsubs ppt.Slides(x).Shapes(y)

    Next y
Next x

MsgBox "Font changed to FontA", vbOKOnly

End Sub

Sub ChangeFontsubs(tshp As Shape)

Dim j As Integer

On Error Resume Next

If tshp.HasTextFrame Then
    tshp.TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Name = "FontA"       
End If

Select Case tshp.Type
Case msoGroup, msoSmartArt
    For j = 1 To tshp.GroupItems.Count
        ChangeFontsubs tshp.GroupItems.Item(j)
    Next j
End Select

End Sub
```

Comment: You might want to edit the question to clarify the problem.  What does "monotype font" mean?  Monotype is a font company but as far as I know, is not a specific kind of font. Do you perhaps mean UNICODE font?  PowerPoint won't allow replacing a unicode or double-byte font with a non-unicode or single-byte font.  You can probably get around this by modifying the underlying XML but it wouldn't be child's play

Comment: Thanks - I did mean unicode/double-byte fonts. 

Is there any way to only embed certain fonts? The problem is actually that when the unicode fonts are embedded they make the presentation huge. Or a way to code a macro which detects where the unicode font is being used (looping through every shape/chart/table in the presentation isn't finding it), so it would be easy for someone to find and delete it

Comment: Writing code to do this is theoretically possible but would be very tedious, considering how many places text can hide.  A single space formatted in a font can trigger embedding.  Ouch.  You can't look just at the shapes that contain text; you have to look at the .TextFrame.TextRange.Runs.Count and for each .Run, check the font.

Answer (score 0):

As Steve says, user text can appear in **many** different places such as:

Slides:

- Placeholders
- Shapes
- Tables
- Charts
- SmartArt
- Comments
- Notes pane

Masters:

- Slide (and layout names)
- Handout
- Notes

Other:

- Shape Names
- Section Names
- Custom Show Names
- Custom Document Properties

The issue with replacing a DBCS (Double Byte Character Set 0-65535) character with a SBCS (Single Byte Character Set, 0-255) character is that is raises the question "what should it be replaced with?". For example, this is the word Tokyo in Japanese : 東京 The two characters are Unicode 26481 and 20140 respectively. A SBCS only has 255 possible characters versus the 65535 for a DBCS so it's not possible to map DBCS to SBCS.

This macro will detect if any DBCS characters exist in any standard shape objects across all slides of a presentation and could used to accept text ranges from all of the above possible occurrences of text within a PowerPoint file:

```
' Nothing passed : Queries every character in every shape in every slide within the presentation for Double Byte Character Set font occurrence
' TextRange passed : Queries every character within the text range for Double Byte Character Set font occurrence
' Returns true if any DBC is found and outputs occurences to the immediate window
Public Function TextRangeHasDBC(Optional trText As TextRange) As Boolean
  Dim oSld As Slide
  Dim oShp As Shape
  Dim cntrChr As Integer
  If trText Is Nothing Then
    For Each oSld In ActivePresentation.Slides
      For Each oShp In oSld.Shapes
        If oShp.HasTextFrame Then
          If oShp.TextFrame.HasText Then
            With oShp.TextFrame.TextRange
              For cntrChr = 1 To Len(.Text)
                If AscW(.Characters(cntrChr, 1)) > 255 Then
                  Debug.Print "DBC found. Slide : "; CStr(oSld.SlideIndex); ", Shape : "; oShp.Name; ", Character "; CStr(cntrChr); " = Unicode "; CStr(AscW(.Characters(cntrChr, 1)))
                  TextRangeHasDBC = True
                End If
              Next
            End With
          End If
        End If
      Next
    Next
  Else
    With trText
      For cntrChr = 1 To Len(.Text)
        If AscW(.Characters(cntrChr, 1)) > 255 Then
          Debug.Print "DBC found. Slide : "; CStr(.Parent.Parent.Parent.SlideIndex); ", Shape : "; .Parent.Parent.Name; ", Character "; CStr(cntrChr); " = Unicode "; CStr(AscW(.Characters(cntrChr, 1)))
          TextRangeHasDBC = True
        End If
      Next
    End With
  End If
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

The only solution to this problem is to do it on XML level. Hence, save the PPT file as XML and then treat it as one long string searching and replacing the fonts you want.